# "bash: _variables: command not found" with autocomplete

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I'm using Debian GNU/Linux 9.12 ( Kernel: Linux 4.9.0-12-amd64 ), and I'm having problems with autocomplete. Autocomplete does work but it shows the message

```
bash: _variables: command not found
```

breaking the word. Example, using TAB to autocomplete `Mi` for the `Minus` folder gives

```bsh
cd Mibash: _variables: command not found
nus/
```

Autocomplete was working fine before. I have recently used

```bsh
source ~/.bashrc
```

and

```bsh
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please edit your question and use the formatting options provided. Also include the contents of `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile`.

Comment: Does the same happen to other user accounts on that system?